# Java - ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException when trying to populate arrays by iterating over a JSONArray

Tags: java, android, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to populate the `server` and the `itemsId` by iterating over a `JSONArray`.

```
String jsonString = '"[{\"label\":\"Label 1\",\"srvid\":1},{\"label\":\"label 2\",\"srvid\":2}]"';

String[] servers = new String[100];
Integer itemsId[] = new Integer[100];
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
        servers[i] = o.getString("label");
        itemsId[i] = o.getInt("srvid");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

However, I am getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` here but I don't know how to further solve this. I wonder what could be wrong in the declaration of the arrays and how they are populated.

Comment: Which line is firing the exception? Also, your example doesn't even compile. Please, post a minimal working example which demonstrates the issue.

Comment: The logcat cannot really show me which line does that however..

Comment: Unlikely. Check it again.

Comment: Before the line starting `for (int i=0...` add `System.out.println(array.length);` and let us know the output, please

Comment: JSON Array length is 2

Comment: You've actually checked that?  I think your array is wrong

Comment: Actually this is what it looks like when I see it in the logcat: 
   [{"srvid":3,"label":"BALIUAG POS"},{"srvid":4,"label":"NOVA POS"}]

Comment: Seems like you are looking for the error in the wrong place. This snip works flawlessly...

Comment: Right.. I actually debugged it now. The error gets from arrayoutofbounds to nullpointerexception. Sorry for bothering you guys just so pressured here. I'll post the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I did is I have initialized the length of the arrays by the size of the JSONArray. And taken them inside the try catch.

```
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    String[] servers = new String[array.length()];
    Integer[] itemsId = new Integer[array.length()];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
        servers[i] = o.getString("label");
        itemsId[i] = o.getInt("srvid");
    }

    //REST OF THE CODES
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I can see here is the single quotes that are enclosing the JSON string. Other than that, the code works flawlessly in Intellij IDEA 2018.1.3.

```
String jsonString = "[{\"label\":\"Label 1\",\"srvid\":1},{\"label\":\"label 2\",\"srvid\":2}]";

String[] servers = new String[100];
Integer itemsId[] = new Integer[100];
try {
    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
        servers[i] = o.getString("label");
        itemsId[i] = o.getInt("srvid");
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(servers)); //Added for testing purposes
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(itemsId)); //Added for testing purposes
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The two `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr))` calls gives the expected output. No problems.

Answer (score 0):

I Executed the following code which is a replica of yours (changed the jsonString).

```
String jsonString = "[{'label':'Label 1','srvid':1},{'label':'label 2','srvid':2}]";

        String[] servers = new String[100];
        Integer itemsId[] = new Integer[100];
        try {
            JSONArray array = new JSONArray(jsonString);
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                servers[i] = o.getString("label");
                System.out.println(servers[i]);
                itemsId[i] = o.getInt("srvid");
                System.out.println(itemsId[i]);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And got the response.

```
Label 1
1
label 2
2
```

So code looks good, if there is nothing wrong with JSON String.